# Stopping strange juddering on keyframe animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have created a keyframe so when I hover on a button it wiggles up and down but I get this weird thing when I hover on the top edge it freaks out, not sure if this is something to do with my code or not. If anyone has any ideas on what is cause this that would be great...

UPDATE: [HERE IS A LINK TO THE BEHAVIOUR](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kw6MjGxP6z2Bvv0Wvr4T5eaBS1j2IWxc/view?usp=sharing)
I slowed it down a bit but that is what I am experiencing...

the button html:

```
<button class="button">Mash!</button>
```

the button css:

```
.button {
  margin-top: 5vh;
  background-color: #000;
   color: #fff; 
   border:none;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   cursor: pointer;
   letter-spacing: 4px;
   padding: 2vw 4vw;
   font-size: 2.5vw;
   font-family: bebas-neue-by-fontfabric;
   font-weight: 700;
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.button:hover{ 
  animation: mash 1000ms infinite alternate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;      
}
```

the animation css:

```
@keyframes mash {
  0% { 
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 3px);
    transform: translate(0, 3px); }
  20% { 
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3px);
    transform: translate(0, -3px); }
  40% { 
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 3px);
    transform: translate(0, 3px); }
  60% { 
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3px);
    transform: translate(0, -3px); }
  80% { 
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 3px);
    transform: translate(0, 3px); }
  100% { 
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3px);
    transform: translate(0, -3px); }
}
```

Comment: I copied your code into a jsfiddle and there is nothing wrong, neither does it show anything you are explaining. Perhaps its the browser ur using?

Comment: I just tried it in codepen to try and replicate the error and same thing, it doesn't happen. It happens for me in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. I am trying to take a screen recording of it but it isn't showing it as it moves too fast...

Comment: I have added a link to show the behaviour

Comment: Is that not expected behaviour, its cause your on the border of the button meaning you reselect it everytime the button fixes 1 loop of the animation.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. Of course! Is there any way of avoiding this?

Comment: I dont know personally, maybe someone will find this post and think about something. Sorry

Comment: Can you provide a codepen, so I can see the problem in action (& change the code).

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in codepen with exactly the same code but the codepen is https://codepen.io/manbearpig349/pen/jOOJERy